# Xamarin Forms Disable ListView Load Animation

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ItemTapped="OnMyItemTapped" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout> CONTENT HERE </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

where `myList` is an `ObservableCollection`

**Desired: Displays all list items immediately at once without animation**

**Actual: Displays list items one at a time (similar to the add item animation)**

Any ideas?

(This sequential displaying of items is significantly more noticeable when the list of items within the list view is larger)

Comment: Maybe try not setting the `ItemSource` binding in XAML and instead set the binding to `ItemSource` after you have pulled in all your items and after you have assigned all your items to your `ObservableCollection`. No positive it will help though.

Comment: @hvaughan3, thanks for the suggestion. i had previously tried that, and the result is the same sadly

Comment: On other thing I can think of would be to hide the `ListView` (`<ListView IsVisible="{Binding HasLoadedListData}">`) until after everything has been loaded. It might be tricky to get the timing right but that might be a workaround for now until you find a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do it is to use a custom renderer.
These are the lines I'm using to disable the *insert*, *delete* and *reload* rows animations:

```
if (e.OldElement != null)
{
    InsertRowsAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.None;
    DeleteRowsAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.None;
    ReloadRowsAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.None;
}
```

This needs to be placed in your `CustomListViewRenderer` that is inheriting from Xamarin forms `ListViewRenderer`.
I put mine in the `OnElementChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a platform specific property to disable animations:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <ListView ios:ListView.RowAnimationsEnabled="false">
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/listview-row-animations